# How do you store evaluated ggplots in R from a list of lists by string?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lazy-evaluation

I am have made a series of lists that contain ggplots. I would like to evaluate the objects in order to bite the plotting time early. I have gathered the variable names that I would like to evaluate in a string vector. Additionally, I want to keep the variable names before.

The solution I tried was to `lapply` the `eval(as.symbol("myvarstring"))`. To my knowledge, it evaluates the variable without storing the evaluated expression.

Adding `as.symbol("myvarstring") <- eval(as.symbol("myvarstring"))` does not work for me.

Below is a minimal reproducible example of my failed solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(
  x = 1:10,
  y = 1:10
)
g <- ggplot(tbl, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()

my_plot_list1 <- list(g,g,g,g,g,g)
my_plot_list2 <- list(g,g,g,g,g,g)
my_plot_list3 <- list(g,g,g,g,g,g)

my_vars <- c(
  "my_plot_list1",
  "my_plot_list2",
  "my_plot_list3"
)

lapply(my_vars, FUN = function(x) {as.symbol(x) <- eval(as.symbol(x))})
```

How would you accomplish this task?

Thank you

EDIT:
These graphs will ultimately be displayed through an `rmarkdown` script. The graphs will be `load`ed in the rscript. My graphs take an enormous amount of time to plot. If I could save an environment with "rendered" graphs, it would shorten the `rmarkdown` runtime. Shortening runtime of the `rmarkdown` runtime is the ultimate goal.

Comment: Did you try `get(x)` ?

Comment: `get(x)` seems to do more or less the same thing as `eval(as.symbol(x))` without the assignment operator. is there a way to render these plots earlier before you "print" the graphs to user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just store the lists in a list, rather than relying on tricks to get them from the global environment?

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(
  x = 1:10,
  y = 1:10
)
g <- ggplot(tbl, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()

my_plot_list1 <- list(g,g,g,g,g,g)
my_plot_list2 <- list(g,g,g,g,g,g)
my_plot_list3 <- list(g,g,g,g,g,g)

my_vars <- list(
  my_plot_list1,
  my_plot_list2,
  my_plot_list3
)

lapply(my_vars, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) y))
```

If you want to ensure that the plots print (eg, if you were to call this code in a function or script) then replace the inner `function(y) y` with `function(y) print(y)`

EDIT: I believe I misunderstood.

If you want to assign variables to a programmatically generated name, you would do:

```
x <- "mygeneratedname"
assign(x, g, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This makes sense but when you call - suppose - `my_plot_list1[1]` - it would seem to re-render the plot before displaying it to the user. Is there a way to save the rendered plots?

Comment: To save to a file, you could use `ggsave(y, file = "myfile.pdf")`

Comment: If I understand `ggsave`, it would save the output to a harddrive. I would like to keep the graph floating in memory so to speak. I'll append some edits further - explaining the ultimate end goal.

Comment: Yes, you can save the plots to the hard drive and then import the images into the Rmarkdown with this syntax: ![](`r filename`) where filename would represent the the path/name of the image.

Comment: I am unsure if that would be a practical solution. In this example, I would want to show 18 `g` plots in the rmarkdown file. Would I need to manually write the filepath to display each graph?

Comment: See the edit. If you just want to save to a variable, try `x <- "myvariable"; assign(x, g); print(myvariable)`

Comment: The function `list.files(path = ".", pattern = ".png", full.names = TRUE)` can provide the file list needed

Answer (score 1):

The `get` function in base R will retrieve the object from the character string.  For example:

```
get("tbl")
# # A tibble: 10 x 2
# x     y
# <int> <int>
# 1     1     1
# 2     2     2
# 3     3     3
# 4     4     4
# 5     5     5
# 6     6     6
# 7     7     7
# 8     8     8
# 9     9     9
# 10    10    10
```

So in your example:

```
 lapply(my_vars, FUN = function(x) { get(x)})
```

should work.

I believe there are better approaches depending on the next steps of what you want to do with the plots.  Consider if this the best way to handle the data.  Can a list of lists work?  Store the lists in a vector?

Comment: This works! I think? My final purpose of all of this is to pass (with `load`) the working environment to a `rmarkdown` file to print the graphs to a `html` file. The graphs I am working with take ages to render. My thought was that if I could render the graphs earlier. I would create a faster run of the `rmarkdown` script.